# Probability of a point being from the same distribution as sample

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, correlation

I have a sample of two-dimensional points {{x_,y_1},..{x_n,y_n}}, I've built a linear regression line, there seems to be a correlation between X and Y (Pearson's 0.662 if that matters).
Now what I need is to have a measure (p-value or something like that) of how likely an additional point {x_n+1,y_n+1} is from the same distribution as the sample. In other words, how "similar" a new point to the points from the sample is.
What are my options - what is a proper Mathematica function(s) to do that?
Sorry if my terminology is not adequate, I am new to all these. I'll provide additional details if needed

Comment: It is about Mathematica - what is a proper function to do that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on CrossValidated (https://stats.stackexchange.com) so that the proper logical framing can be found.  (For example, if you have a random sample from a bivariate distribution, a linear regression is not what you want.)  Then back here for how to implement a solution.

Comment: To calculate something like a $p$-value, you could (1) estimate a probability distribution $P(x,y)$ of the sample, for example a bivariate normal distribution, and then (2) for the new point $(x',y')$ you calculate $P(x',y')$, and then (3) integrate the distribution to find the likelihood that when we draw a point randomly  from $P$ we find a value $P(x,y)\ge P(x',y')$. I'm not sure this is 100% correct; agreeing with @JimB that this is a question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: For a 1D normal distribution characterized by mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, the above recipe gives a meaningful answer: if $x'=\mu$ then we get 1 (100% likelihood that $x'$ was drawn from the normal distribution); if $x'=\mu\pm\sigma$, we get $\text{erfc}(1/\sqrt{2})=31.7\%$; if $x'=\mu\pm2\sigma$, we get $\text{erfc}(2/\sqrt{2})=4.6\%$; if $x'=\mu\pm3\sigma$, we get $\text{erfc}(3/\sqrt{2})=0.27\%$; etc. and these numbers may look familiar to you (or rather one minus these numbers).

Comment: All this to say that there are many functions in Mathematica that can help to estimate this kind of problem (see my answer below) and so it’s maybe premature to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the above comment:

Let's assume that we have a sample of 2D points, generated here at random (fill in your points instead):

```
SeedRandom[1234];
samples = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{0.3, 0.7}, {{1, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.3}}], 100];
```

Fit a bivariate normal distribution `P` to these sample points:

```
P = EstimatedDistribution[samples,
      MultinormalDistribution[{μx, μy}, {{σxx, σxy}, {σxy, σyy}}]];
ContourPlot[PDF[P, {x, y}],
  {x, Min[samples[[All, 1]]], Max[samples[[All, 1]]]},
  {y, Min[samples[[All, 2]]], Max[samples[[All, 2]]]},
  PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  Epilog -> {Red, Point[samples]}]
```

[image]

Now we have a new sample, drawn again at random (replace with your $\{x_{n+1},y_{n+1}\}$):

```
newsample = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 2]
(*    {1.44527, -0.823658}    *)
```

The probability for distribution `P` to generate a sample that has a lower or equal PDF than this `newsample` can be calculated with the [`RarerProbability`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RarerProbability.html) function:

```
RarerProbability[P, newsample]
(*    seems to take forever...    *)
```

Much faster: for a bivariate normal distribution, we can calculate this rarer probability simply with

```
PDF[P, newsample] / PDF[P, Mean[P]]
(*    0.000196346    *)
```

(For other distributions, the formula differs!). So in this case, we could say that the `newsample` was probably not from the same distribution as the `sample`, because this $p$-value of 0.02% suggests rejecting the null hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

I feel it might be very hard to determine with confidence whether a single point does or does not come from the same distribution as another set of points, as there is not a lot of information to go on. And if it came from a very similar distribution (but not the same) it would be hard to tell. I hope an expert can come answer this.

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but as a quick test could you create an empirical distribution using your dataset {{x_,y_1},...,{x_n,y_n}} (this can be accomplished with the `EmpiricalDistribution[]` function or if you know what type of distribution the data should follow using the `EstimatedDistribution[]` function) and then use the value of the estimated pdf at the point {x_n+1,y_n+1} sort of as a quick test for whether or not you think that point comes from that distribution?

If instead of one point, you had multiple points to test simultaneously ({{x_n+1,y_n+1},...,{x_n+m,y_n+m}} you could use the `KolmogorovSmirnovTest[]` function to test whether the data comes from your `EstimatedDistribution[]` (I do not know if `KolmogorovSmirnovTest[]` works with `EmpiricalDistribution[]` however).

Comment: Thank you, David. I indeed have only one additional point to compare - it is an "unusual" case and the question is how to quantify how "unusual" it is compared to "usual" cases from the sample. 
Do you know if linear regression of the sample can help? Maybe, there is a way to quantify how far away from the regression line is the "unusual" case in comparison to the average distance of sample points?

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you could create something like a 95% "envelope" around the regression line that contains 95% of the data points for each x value? So discretize x space, and in each x bin find the bounds around the regression line that contain 95% of the points in that bin, and reject data that falls outside of that envelope. Could this work? I want to reiterate however, I do think there are better people to answer this question and I hope someone sees this and can help you.

Comment: [This stack exchange thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83163/statistical-test-to-tell-whether-two-samples-are-pulled-from-the-same-population) may have some useful information in case you have not seen it

But again the linked post is more about testing multiple points at once compared to just a single point